# Does this method really work to catch rats?

Tags: realism, manu

In [Manu (2018)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manu_(film)), Manu use this method to catch rats:

A strong rope, three tomatoes, a cycle bar, some oil and an iron box.
It's the only trap to catch rats safely. They smell the tomatoes,
crawl onto the rope and climb into the box. They enter the hole with the
help of the bar. They can never come out of it. Even if they tried,
the oil won't allow them.

[image]

Does this method really work to catch rats?

Comment: This seems to be a question about rat catching and not about movies or TV

Comment: @ToddWilcox You can see this similar [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/111567/do-people-really-open-wine-bottles-with-an-army-sword) discuss about wine opening
which is clearly not movie question. That's where "Realism" tag comes into play.

Comment: You can catch rats in anything they can get into but can't get out of. A two gallon can like that they could probably jump out, even if the hole in the top is quite small. You'd attract more if it was against the wall rather than in the open. rats like to stick close to walls when they can.

Comment: It is most assuredly possible to make a rat-trap in that fashion. Therefor, the scene is realistic. Will that trap actually trap the rats permanently? Different question.

Comment: Realism Qs are accepted here. There is nothing with the Q. But one thing that might make the Q better, is to ask if this method is, or ever was, a more common method? Or of there is a reason the filmmaker chose to do it this way? Otherwise you might leave yourself open to smart *ss answers such as: if I build it and call it a rat trap, is it a rat trap? As opposed to this being a method that at one time or another might have been more commonly used, although I suspect the reflection of the character/character's perceived reality comment, might also be a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen the movie & likely never will, but I get the impression it's supposed to be [possibly to fit a character profile] intentionally 'Heath Robinson'. More complex than it needs to be, whilst being kind of 'fun' in its design rather than purely efficient.

You can catch rats in anything they can't get out of again, so it might theoretically attract them [google says rats like tomatoes] and provide a more-than-necessarily-complex way for them to be able to get in, then a 'greasy pole' to stop them climbing out.
The image, as presented, looks small enough they could probably jump out without needing the pole, even if the access hole was quite small.

You can catch rats in a box-section tube with gently-sprung plexi-glass flaps at each end. If they think they can see right through they will have no hesitation going inside. Place it against a wall/floor junction so they can pass through it as they traverse the room edges and they'll happily open one end to walk in… then discover they can't open either end from the inside. There's no place inside to grip or chew, so they're stuck.
Rats are not stupid though, en masse. If they see a couple of mates get stuck that way, the rest will learn to avoid it.

Comment: For the Americans out there, "Heath Robinson" is the British Rube Goldberg. For greasy poles as a deterrent and avoiding seeing their mates get stuck, see: https://www.cbssports.com/nfl/news/look-philly-cops-grease-poles-with-waterproof-hydraulic-fluid-to-stop-eagles-fans/